# Monitoring microservice using grafana

Tags: microservices, grafana, health-monitoring, statsd, telegraf

We are having multpile microservices which have health end points in the form of JSON. A JSON may contain states of other services that a microservice will call. Is there a way we can monitor this service on Grafana?. We have Grafana and Telegraf.

Thx in advance
sam

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I believe the [Telegraf HTTP plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/http) has JSON parsing and can satisfy this.

If you're just doing plain health checks though, I imagine you may have something like service discovery which pretty much has plain HTTP health checking out of the box.

That aside, one suggestion I have is actually break up the health checks for independent services. That is to say, that if you aggregated it at a top level microservice and that microservice fails for whatever reason, your monitoring would show a false positive for the failure for the other services behind that microservice that may be up. This goes hand in hand with service discovery if you're just looking for a plain 200 OK HTTP status code.